# Tension on either side of a massive pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When a pulley has mass, why is tension on both the sides different? Why don't we consider rotation of pulley when it is massless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Newton's law for rotating bodies:
$$
\alpha = \frac{\tau}{I}
$$

Where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration, $\tau$ is the torque on the object and $I$ is its moment of inertia.

When a pulley has mass, it has a non-zero moment of inertia. This means that it requires a torque for it to accelerate. This torque is obtained from the difference in tension on both sides.

In the case of a massless pulley, the moment of inertia is zero and hence no torque is required for its acceleration, so the tension on both sides can be equal even though it accelerates.